# Can a specific character be deleted from every span class?

Tags: python, html

I have many html files with span classes

```
span class="special-level-1"
span class="special-level-2"
span class="special-level-3"
span class="special-level-4"
span class="special-level-5"
```

I want to delete every `*` that occurs inside one of these span classes.

I've started a python script

```
import sys
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html import parse

doc = parse(sys.argv[1])
span1 = doc.find('//span[@class="special-level-1"]')
span2 = doc.find('//span[@class="special-level-2"]')
span3 = doc.find('//span[@class="special-level-3"]')
span4 = doc.find('//span[@class="special-level-4"]')
span5 = doc.find('//span[@class="special-level-5"]')
span1.getparent().replace("\*", "")
span2.getparent().replace("\*", "")
span3.getparent().replace("\*", "")
span4.getparent().replace("\*", "")
span5.getparent().replace("\*", "")
print etree.tostring(doc)
```

but this doesn't work. Can this script be salvaged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can seriously simplify your code, by using the following XPath expression:

```
//span[starts-with(@class, "special-level-")]
```

Then, use the `xpath()` method and set the `text` value of each node to a result of `replace()`:

```
for elm in doc.xpath('.//span[starts-with(@class, "special-level-")]'):
    elm.text = elm.text.replace("\*", "")  # not sure why not just "*"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm pretty new to python (as evidenced by the `\*` instead of  just `*`).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because strings are **immutable** in python.

```
span5.getparent().replace("\*", "") #=> new string without the *
```

You must *reassign* the new string in order for this to work